# Angular 5 - Two way data binding not working

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm not getting it... I'd like to do a get request on my service which gives me the specific hardware for the barcode i scanned - this works already.

I get the correct hardware back as an object, looks like this ->

[image]

But if I want to display this object now, I only get `[object Object]` in my frontend.

**component.html**

```
{{ terminal }}
```

**component.ts**

```
terminal: any[] = [];

constructor(private terminalService: TerminalService) { }

this.terminalService.getTerminalByBarcode(barcode).subscribe(terminal => {
   console.log(terminal.terminal);
   this.terminal = terminal.terminal;
});
```

I already tried with `terminal: Object;` but that doesn't change anything. Hope someone can tell me, where I'm thinking wrong of two way data binding?

Comment: What do you exactly want to display on the UI as in what properties of the object you want to display??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `terminal.terminal` is an object, the output of `{{ terminal }}` is OK to be `[object Object]`, because it calls `toString` on that object.

To see the structure of the `terminal` you can use `json` pipe

```
{{ terminal | json }}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, `| json` is what did the trick! Will accept your answer as soon as it's possible

Answer (score 1):

It's because on your view you are trying to output the actual object .toString.

You need to output the objects properties like the following:

```
{{ terminal.barcode }}
{{ terminal.dateArrival }}
```